# How to format the resource for Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId) to create a column group

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

- I'm trying to create a column group.
- I've enabled Sheets API version 4.
- I've looked at the reference in [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#adddimensiongrouprequest)
- Using code completion I've come up with this code:

  `function makeColumnGroup() {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet21');
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"range":[{dimension:"COLUMNS",startIndex:1,endIndex:3,sheetId:sh.getSheetId()}]},ss.getId());
  }`

I've been through several different versions but as it stands now I'm getting the Error:

`Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "range": Cannot find field. (line 4, file "20181212")`

But in the API reference it shows that the AddDimensionGroupRequest in JSON format looks like this:

`{
  "range": {
    object(DimensionRange)
  }
}`

the the DimensionRange looks like this:

`{
  "sheetId": number,
  "dimension": enum(Dimension),
  "startIndex": number,
  "endIndex": number
}`

Code Completion suggests a format as follows:

`Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId)`

but I can't seem to come up with the magic formula for figuring out the format for that resource.  Past experiences suggest a format such as this with the Drive API:

`Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": subFldr.getId()}]}, res.getId());`

But this is not working if I used the format suggested by the Sheets API:

`Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"range":{dimension:"COLUMNS",startIndex:1,endIndex:3,sheetId:sh.getSheetId()}},ss.getId());`

I get the error:

`Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "range": Cannot find field. (line 4, file "20181212")`

**The question:**
How do I format the **resource** parameter?

Comment: The bit to remember is that you're submitting a **batch** of updates. So the signature requires an array of the individual updates, even when there's just one update.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for that.  I appreciate the help.  I really like the API explorer because sometimes I need to see a working example. This one `Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": subFldr.getId()}]}, res.getId());` was provided by @tanaike and has helped to solve other problems.

Comment: Note that the Drive API example is for a single known method - `Files#update` - while the `Spreadsheet#batchUpdate` is a generic container that doesn't even mention the specific method being invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for you, as another method, you can also use the methods for creating requests with Sheets of Advanced Google Service. When you try to use Sheets of Advanced Google Service on the script editor, you might see some methods by the auto completion. When such methods are used, the required parameters can be known by the auto completion with the script editor. So I think that it will make us easily create the requests. As a sample, the request body in your answer can be created like this sample.

#### Sample script:

```
function makeColumnGroup() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set parameters of addDimensionGroup
  var p = Sheets.newAddDimensionGroupRequest();
  p.range = Sheets.newGridRange();
  p.range.dimension = "COLUMNS";
  p.range.startIndex = 1;
  p.range.endIndex = 3;
  p.range.sheetId = ss.getSheetId();

  // Create single request
  var req = Sheets.newRequest();
  req.addDimensionGroup = p;

  // Create batch requests
  var batchReq = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
  batchReq.requests = [req];

  // Request
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchReq, ss.getId());
}
```

#### Note:

- When `batchReq` is confirmed, it is found that it is the same with your request body.
- Unfortunately, I couldn't find the official documents related to these methods. I thought that it might suppose that users find the methods by the auto completion.

### Edit:

For example, when a group is created, in order to collapse the group, how about this sample script? In this sample script, it creates the requests of `addDimensionGroup` and `updateDimensionGroup`. These requests are run by `batchUpdate`.

#### Sample script:

```
function makeColumnGroup() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set range
  var range = Sheets.newGridRange();
  range.dimension = "COLUMNS";
  range.startIndex = 1;
  range.endIndex = 3;
  range.sheetId = ss.getSheetId();

  // Create request of addDimensionGroup
  var p1 = Sheets.newAddDimensionGroupRequest();
  p1.range = range;
  var req1 = Sheets.newRequest();
  req1.addDimensionGroup = p1;

  // Create request of updateDimensionGroup
  var p2 = Sheets.newUpdateDimensionGroupRequest();
  p2.dimensionGroup = Sheets.newDimensionGroup();
  p2.dimensionGroup.collapsed = true;
  p2.dimensionGroup.depth = 1;
  p2.dimensionGroup.range = range;
  p2.fields = "*";
  var req2 = Sheets.newRequest();
  req2.updateDimensionGroup = p2;

  // Create batch requests
  var batchReq = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
  batchReq.requests = [req1, req2];

  // Request
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchReq, ss.getId());
}
```

Comment: I'm going to look this over carefully.  I tried doing something like it but I didn't know to declare `p.range = Sheets.newGridRange();` In fact, I've never used newGridRange() before but this looks pretty good.  Have you ever added `collapsed:true, depth:1`.  I was wondering how to do that but just decided to go with `sh.collapseAllColumnGroups();` I'll get back here later as I'm working on getting files out of a certain folder in a teamdrive right now.

Comment: @Cooper In the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that there are no same method with ``collapseAllColumnGroups()`` in Sheets API. If you want to run ``collapseAllColumnGroups()`` by Sheets API, how about this workaround? 1. Retrieve ``columnGroups`` using ``spreadsheets.get``. 2. Using the ranges retrieved from ``columnGroups``, it updates ``columnGroups`` by ``updateDimensionGroup``.

Comment: @Cooper In [the document of DimensionRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DimensionRange) for ``startIndex`` and ``endIndex``, ``not set if unbounded.`` can be read. But if those properties are not set, an error of ``INVALID_ARGUMENT`` occurs.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  This is great stuff.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. I'm glad that is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow I figured it out.  Here's the code:

```
function makeColumnGroup() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet21');
  var res={
  "requests": [
    {
      "addDimensionGroup": {
        "range": {
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 3,
          "sheetId": 1163414414
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(res,ss.getId());

}
```

It just boiled down to copying the code right from the API Explorer.  I'll try to remember that in the future. I'm going to leave this unchecked in case one of the more knowledgeable volunteers has a better solution.

[image]